# How to add smooth transition to my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of, sorry for my bad javascript knowledge. I only yesterday started learning it and understanding it is quite hard in short time. I'm a designer so coding is not my specialty but I'd like to learn at least basics.

So now enough of excuses. I'd like to know why in my code, when I press on image, when it enlarges no animation shows up, but when I close it - animation shows up.

I've tried adding opacity and transitions everywhere

```js
$('img[data-enlargable]')
  .addClass('img-enlargable')
  .click(function(){
    $('.open-overlay')
      .css({
        opacity: '1',
        transition:'all .3s ease',
        visibility: 'visible',
        background: 'RGBA(0,0,0,.5)',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        width:'100%', height:'100%',
        position:'fixed',
        zIndex:'999999',
        top:'0',
        bottom:'0',
        left:'0',
        right:'0',
        cursor: 'zoom-out'
      })
      .click(function(){

        //when pressed on open-overlay div - close
        $('<div>')
          .css({
            opacity:'0',
            transition:'all .3s ease',
            visibility: 'hidden'
          });
      })
      .appendTo('body');

    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('<div>')
      .css({
        opacity:'1',
        transition:'all .3s ease',
        background: 'url('+src+') no-repeat center',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        width:'90%', height:'90%',
        position:'fixed',
        zIndex:'999999',
        visibility: 'visible',
        top:'5%',
        bottom:'0',
        left:'5%',
        right:'0',
        cursor: 'zoom-out'
      })
      .click(function(){

          //when pressed on image - close
          $(this).remove();

          $('.open-overlay')
            .css({
              opacity: '0',
              transition:'all .3s ease',
              visibility: 'hidden'
            });  
      })
      .appendTo('body');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="work-img"><img data-enlargable style="cursor: zoom-in" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" /></div>

<div class="open-overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, You problem is that You're appending div to body on every click. Because of this animation dosesn't work correctly. Also div with image is not animated and that's because You're append it body and then immediately try to animate it to show up.

I've shorten Your function a little bit. Also few words of explanation for `requestAnimationFrame`. To prevent immediate animation after appending div to body, I'm waiting for browser, to be ready, to render new frame and then also waiting 20ms which is 1000ms (1 second) / 60 frames  = 16.66 ms to have 60fps animation. Rounding UP to 20. Could be even 17. Without timeout function it works 50/50.

As a side note. All of this code can be even more reduced by using CSS class instead of jQuery `.css()` function. But I just focused to make it work.

```js
$('img[data-enlargable]')
  .addClass('img-enlargable')
  .click(function(){
    $('.open-overlay')
      .css({
        opacity : 1,
        visibility : 'visible'
      });
    
    const IMAGE_POPUP = $('<div>')
      .css({
        opacity:'0',
        transition:'all .3s ease',
        visibility: 'hidden',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        width:'90%', height:'90%',
        position:'fixed',
        zIndex:'999999',
        visibility: 'hidden',
        top:'5%',
        bottom:'0',
        left:'5%',
        right:'0',
        cursor: 'zoom-out'
      })
      .click(function(){

          //when pressed on image - close
          $(this).remove();

          $('.open-overlay')
            .css({
              opacity: '0',
              visibility: 'hidden'
            });  
      })
      .appendTo('body');
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const IMAGE_SOURCE = this.src;
        IMAGE_POPUP
          .css({
            opacity:'1',
            background: 'url(' + IMAGE_SOURCE + ') no-repeat center',
            visibility: 'visible',
          });
      }, 20);
    });
  });
```

```css
.open-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="work-img"><img data-enlargable style="cursor: zoom-in" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" /></div>

<div class="open-overlay"></div>
```

Here's proposed solution:

```js
$('img[data-enlargable]')
  .addClass('img-enlargable')
  .click(function(){
    $('.open-overlay').addClass('is-visible');
    
    const IMAGE_POPUP = $('<div>')
      .addClass('image_popup')
      .click(function(){

          //when pressed on image - close
          $(this).remove();

          $('.open-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
      })
      .appendTo('body');
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const IMAGE_SOURCE = this.src;
        IMAGE_POPUP
          .addClass('is-visible')
          .css({
            background: 'url(' + IMAGE_SOURCE + ') no-repeat center',
          });
      }, 20);
    });
  });
```

```css
.open-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: zoom-out;
}

.open-overlay.is-visible, .image_popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.image_popup {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 5%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  right: 0;
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="work-img"><img data-enlargable style="cursor: zoom-in" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" /></div>

<div class="open-overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're using `.appendTo('body');` after modifying the css. Removing that is enough to make the code work:

```js
$('img[data-enlargable]').addClass('img-enlargable').click(function(){
     $('.open-overlay').css({
      
      //
   
          opacity: '1',
          transition:'all .3s ease',
      visibility: 'visible',
       background: 'RGBA(0,0,0,.5)',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        width:'100%', height:'100%',
        position:'fixed',
        zIndex:'999999',
        top:'0', bottom:'0', left:'0', right:'0',
          cursor: 'zoom-out'
    
    }).click(function(){
    
    
       //when pressed on open-overlay div - close
          $('<div>').css({
    opacity:'0',
  transition:'all .3s ease',
          visibility: 'hidden'
    
  
          });
    
    });
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('<div>').css({
  
  opacity:'1',
  transition:'all .3s ease',
        background: 'url('+src+') no-repeat center',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        width:'90%', height:'90%',
        position:'fixed',
        zIndex:'999999',
  
          visibility: 'visible',
        top:'5%', bottom:'0', left:'5%', right:'0',
        cursor: 'zoom-out'
  }).click(function(){
    
       //when pressed on image - close
         $(this).remove();
          
          
          $('.open-overlay').css({
          opacity: '0',
    
          transition:'all .3s ease',
          visibility: 'hidden'
          });
          
  }).appendTo('body');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work-img"><img data-enlargable style="cursor: zoom-in" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" /></div>

<div class="open-overlay"></div>
```

That being said, you could tidy this up a little bit. I would suggest having your `.open-overlay` css clearly defined somewhere else, and then only modify the parts that you need with jQuery. For example you don't need to modify 
the `transition` property every time you do something, you can define that in your css and only modify the `opacity` and `visibility` properties in jQuery.. Here's what I mean:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('img[data-enlargable]').addClass('img-enlargable').click(function(){
     $('.open-overlay').css({   
          opacity: '1',
          visibility: 'visible',
          cursor: 'zoom-out'
    
    });
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('<div>').css({
  
  opacity:'1',
  transition:'all .3s ease',
        background: 'url('+src+') no-repeat center',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        width:'90%', height:'90%',
        position:'fixed',
        zIndex:'999999',
  
          visibility: 'visible',
        top:'5%', bottom:'0', left:'5%', right:'0',
        cursor: 'zoom-out'
  }).click(function(){
    
       //when pressed on image - close
         
          $(this).remove();
          
          $('.open-overlay').css({
          opacity: '0',
          visibility: 'hidden'
          });
          }).appendTo('body');
          
  });
         })
```

```css
.open-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work-img"><img data-enlargable style="cursor: zoom-in" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" /></div>

<div class="open-overlay"></div>
```

I would also recommend you check this example out which explains how to achieve something very similar to what you're trying to do:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Comment: Thanks for detail answer! That helped a lot :)